# Apache says DocumentRoot doesn't exist when it does

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I used Webmin to create the following Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/whatever"
        ServerName whatever.ourdomain
        <Directory "/var/www/whatever">
                allow from all
                Options +Indexes
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And when restarting Apache I get

```
Starting httpd: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/whatever] does not exist
```

The thing is, the directory absolutely DOES exist. I'm staring right at it. `pwd` shows me that's my current directory, etc. It's not that hard to spell it right. I can't find any other errors or warnings in the httpd logs. apache:apache owns the directory and all subdirectories/files. There isn't any symlinks or anything involved here. What am I missing or what else should I look at to determine why this is?

OS is CentOS 6.0

Comment: su to the Apache user and see if it can access the `DocumentRoot`, that might give you some insight into what the web server is seeing.   You may also want to check the other directories along the path, though if it's really under `/var/www/` those should not be a problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing that popped into my mind is does Apache have permission to access that directory?

Also, this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948038/apache-says-my-documentroot-directory-doesnt-exist

Comment: As I said, yes the directory is owned by `apache:apache`, however I followed that link (that is on SO for some reason?) and indeed SELinux was the problem. SELinux causes more problems that it does good imo.

Comment: selinux is annoying at first, but if you know the commands to manage access, it is actually not as daunting. It's a good tool to use once you get used to it.

Comment: I had the same issue (Doesn't exist on a symlink), and running `setenforce 0` fixed it, but looking at the permissions `ls-laZ`, the symlink has the same permissions as other files it can access, apart from chmod. The files are -rw-r--r--, and the symlink is lrwxrwxrwx. Could that be the reason it doesn't work with setenforce 1?

Comment: @JakeWilson SELinux is rather frustrating when you're first getting accustomed to it. The more you learn how to use it, I promise you will appreciate it much more.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a tutorial approach to the SELinux case:

Find out if SELinux is active:

```
 $ sestatus
 SELinux status:                 enabled
 SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
 Current mode:                   enforcing
 Mode from config file:          enforcing
 Policy version:                 24
 Policy from config file:        targeted
```

If so, some comparative checking might help.  For instance, a server has a default DocumentRoot at `/var/www/html`, but we want it somewhere else like `/path/to/document/root`.

If SELinux is not actively messing with the resource, `ls -dZ` on the directory will show something like:

```
$ ls -dZ /path/to/document/root
? /path/to/document/root/
```

On the other hand, if SELinux contexts are applied, `ls -dZ` looks more like:

```
$ ls -dZ /path/to/document/root
drwxrws--x+ cfgadm cfgadmin system_u:object_r:file_t:s0 /path/to/document/root
```

If we compare to a working DocumentRoot, it would look something like:

```
$ ls -dZ /var/www/html
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/html
```

The `_r` and `_t` relate to `-r` (`--role` and `-t` (`--type`) arguments to `chcon`.  Here is a cut-down man page:

```
NAME
   chcon - change file security context

SYNOPSIS
   chcon [OPTION]... CONTEXT FILE...
   chcon [OPTION]... [-u USER] [-r ROLE] [-l RANGE] [-t TYPE] FILE...
   chcon [OPTION]... --reference=RFILE FILE...

DESCRIPTION
   Change the security context of each FILE to CONTEXT.  With --reference,
   change the security context of each FILE to that of RFILE.

   --reference=RFILE
          use RFILE's security context rather than  specifying a CONTEXT value

   -R, --recursive
          operate on files and directories recursively
```

At first guess, the following might seem to work, but might not.

```
$ sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/document/root
```

If the web server still cannot see the DocumentRoot, note that the context matters all the way back to root:

```
$ sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/document
$ sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/to
$ sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /path
```

At this point, the web server can see the directory.

Yes, I learned the hard way tonight.

NOTE:  The use of *chcon* conceptually has a downside per RedHat documentation ([5.6.1. Temporary Changes: chcon](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files)) that states:

```
The chcon command changes the SELinux context for files. However, changes
made with the chcon command do not survive a file system relabel, or the
execution of the restorecon command.
```

Use *semanage* and *restorecon* to make more permanent changes.  A brief example:

```
 $ sudo semanage fcontext --add -t httpd_sys_content_t -s system_u \
     "/path/to/document/root(/.*)?"
 $ sudo restorecon -FR /path/to/document/root
```

With regards to *restorecon*, note that *-F* is required to affect the whole context (i.e. user and type).  Also, *-R* means to make changes recursively.  Arguments *-v* or *-p* can show progress in either a verbose or terse fashion.  Use *-FRnv* to see what would happen without actually making any changes.

Once *semanage* is used in this way, it is possible to view local security changes with a command like:

```
$ sudo semanage export
```

The output of *semanage export* may be saved and used by *semanage import* to make it easier to apply a set of changes to various systems.

NOTE: This answer provides a most basic type context for a site.  Security can be much more granular.  For example, see a list of types that can apply to web server pages with a command like:

```
$ seinfo -t | grep http
```

NOTE: Utilities like *semanage* and *seinfo* may not be installed by default.  At least on some distributions, required packages may be named something like this:

```
policycoreutils-python
setools-console
```

Comment: Detailed, works and saves a lot of time - thank you!

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like SELinux.I would suggest you work with it. Look in the /var/log/audit directory to confirm.

Worse case, you can always turn off selinux, as noted earlier, but I suggest you work with it instead. For instance, if I were to create a directory for use with Apache, it will not have the right context, as noted here.

```
[root@amp23140 www]# ls -Z
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 error
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 html
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 icons
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 whatever
```

So if that happens, I just apply the context from another directory, which in this case, is html:

```
[root@amp23140 www]# chcon whatever --reference=html
[root@amp23140 www]# ls -lZ
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 error
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 html
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 icons
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command in root to change the security context of “httpd_sys_content_t” which allows Apache to execute.

```
chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/whatever
```

Use `ls -dZ /var/www/whatever` to view the details security roles