# Two identical files; Apache says one is forbidden

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, permissions

I've got this one file, favicon.ico. It's actually a large group of nested files, but purely for example, just this one.

If I do `cp favicon.ico favicon2.ico`, Apache can read the second one just fine.

If I do `mv favicon.ico favicon3.ico`, Apache throws a 403 on favicon3.ico.

If I `su apache`, I can read the file as apache.

`stat` says both files are identical, except for the inode number.

Is there some hidden flag somewhere or something that I'm missing? I've never seen anything like this.

`error_log` says `(13)Permission denied: access to /favicon3.ico denied`

Comment: Are you sure the `/favicon3.ico` path is OK?

Comment: An answer to another question might offer assistance to others running across this question; it presents a more broad approach to dealing with SELinux issues and web servers : https://serverfault.com/a/551801/101931

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SELinux is denying you access to the file, since [you *moved* instead of *copied* it](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Maintaining_SELinux_Labels_.html) from somewhere else on the filesystem into its final location. Thus it kept its original security context, which didn't allow Apache to access it.

To resolve the issue, relabel the file (and probably all the rest of your files).

For example:

```
restorecon -r -v /var/www/html
```

To avoid the problem in future, copy files (and delete the original if necessary).