# Nginx static file configuration for CenotOS 7 Minimal Installation

Tags: nginx, http, localhost

I have a brand new VM with CenotOS 7 Minimal Installation.

What I want to happen is to configure Nginx to serve static files from a directory on `localhost:80`.

My directory is `/home/kenny/projects/kcrypt/dist/`.

Here are the contents of my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
# this is set to root in order to rule out
# any permission related issues.
user root;    

worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        root         /home/kenny/projects/kcrypt/dist/;
        index index.html;

        location / {
        }
    }
}
```

when I run `curl http://localhost` I get this response:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.12.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried giving all kinds of permissions to any directories that I can think of.

In the end I configured Nginx to run as root.

I have reinstalled the OS multiple times already and can't get it to work.

P.S.

This is what I found in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
2018/02/27 21:33:19 [error] 15689#0: *1 open() "/home/kenny/projects/kcrypt/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: ::1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2018/02/27 21:33:35 [error] 15690#0: *2 open() "/home/kenny/projects/kcrypt/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2018/02/27 21:33:38 [error] 15690#0: *3 open() "/home/kenny/projects/kcrypt/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: ::1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

I don't get what it wants... I have given it all the permissions that I can.

This is what I have in the root directory:

```
[root@vm3 dist]# ll
total 368K
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root   98 Feb 26 23:16 .
drwxrwxrwx. 6 root root  234 Feb 27 21:26 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 1.2K Feb 26 23:16 favicon.ico
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 1.7K Feb 26 23:16 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 175K Feb 26 22:53 index.js
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  297 Feb 26 23:16 manifest.json
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 179K Feb 26 22:53 styles.css
```

P.S. 2

I have tried putting my static files in `/var/www/kcrypt/dist/`, but with no result.

I still get the same error messages:

```
2018/02/27 23:18:11 [error] 16157#0: *1 open() "/var/www/kcrypt/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: ::1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2018/02/27 23:20:58 [error] 16535#0: *1 open() "/var/www/kcrypt/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: ::1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2018/02/27 23:21:30 [error] 16564#0: *1 open() "/var/www/kcrypt/dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: ::1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: @AaronCopley You can see from his question that the answer is yes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Nah, I had a hunch but missed anything obvious showing it. Good answer below.

Comment: @AaronCopley The `.` at the right of the permissions list indicates that the file has a security context. These only show up when SELinux is enabled (enforcing or permissive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your system has SELinux enabled. By default SELinux does not allow the web server to read files in users' home directories. The directories enabled for web serving are `/var/www` (where system packages place files) and `/srv/www` (where users are expected to place files in production).

If you need to serve files from home directories, you can set the SELinux boolean `httpd_read_user_content`, which will allow these files to be read.

```
setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
```

Keep in mind that SELinux will never allow the web server to *write* in user home directories. If you need this, you will need to place your web content elsewhere and [make the appropriate directories writable](https://serverfault.com/q/626610/126632).

---

Also keep in mind that SELinux works *in addition to* regular UNIX permissions, so the relevant files and directories must also have the appropriate ownership and permissions, whatever they will be for your specific use case.

Comment: I have updated my question. I moved the files to `/var/www/kcrypt/dist/` but nothing changed.

Comment: @HristoKolev Did you check the existing permissions and SELinux contexts? If you [moved the files](https://serverfault.com/a/801732/126632) then the contexts are probably wrong. In that case you will need to [fix them](https://serverfault.com/a/487239/126632).