# SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from getattr access after switching to self signed cert

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl, selinux, lets-encrypt

I recently created my own CA and issued my first root cert, then intermediate, then finally a server cert/key/chain for apache.

When i switch from the letsencrypt certs added with certbot to the self generated certs, apache fails to start with:

> Dec 20 07:52:07 test setroubleshoot[4859]: SELinux is preventing
>   /usr/sbin/httpd from getattr access on the file
>   /root/ca/intermediate/certs/www.inthingslimited.com

I'm wondering if maybe its some of the letsencrypt defaults causing me headaches or is it simply that the certs dont trace back to a registered CA?

I've read that i could disable SELinux but I think it would be better to find a solution that allowed me to leave SELinux alone.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: output from journalctl -xe

Comment: This msg is in the journlctl -xe output but the ausearch command just hangs.

You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do allow this access for now by executing:
      # ausearch -c 'httpd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-httpd
      # semodule -i my-httpd.pp

Comment: setenforce 0 

disables SELinux and apache service starts.  

Im guessing SELinux doesn't like certs not from a registered CA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELinux does not allow Apache to access anything in the `/root` directory, full stop. It doesn't matter if it's certificates, web site static files, or anything else.

To solve the problem, copy the certificate files into appropriate directories under `/etc/pki/tls`.

Comment: Well I looked into that and I'm not sure that was the issue. The domain was functioning properly with the letsencrypt certs added via certbot to /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.inthingslimited.com/ and that is where I placed my self signed certs (I also made sure to duplicate the security to mimic letsencrypt certs 644) so if security was a problem wouldnt it be for the letsencrypt certs as well?

Comment: @doapydave No, because that directory is also allowed, but you probably had the wrong file contexts due to [moving files instead of copying them](https://serverfault.com/a/801732/126632).

Comment: I copied them to /etc/pki/tls as suggested and all is well now.  Your other mention about file contexts was also helpful.  I will try that on the orig location i was having trouble with.  it will probably fix that too. Thank you very much!