# OpenResty permission denied even though user has access when testing with sudo

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, permissions, openresty

I have a weird issue I can't seem to figure out.

I am using OpenResty. The way it should work on that particular server is that the whole configuration and Lua scripts and everything comes from a Git repo. The `ubuntu` user should manage the repository and OpenResty's workers should run as `www-data` (I've set `user www-data www-data;` in the config). I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

The repository is located at `/home/ubuntu/app/my-project` and acts as prefix for OpenResty.

It seems however like the worker processes can't access anything in that directory (the main process can). The Lua files are not executed (there is no error about that either, though), some config values seem to be ignored, and I get "error 13: permission denied" when trying to write into `temp/client_body/...` and also when reading from `html/index.html` and such:

```
open() "/home/ubuntu/app/my-project/temp/client_body/0000093402" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

All the files and directories within the project are set to group `www-data`, and the `temp` directory which holds `client_body` and such even has an *owner* of `www-data`, and the read/write permissions are set correctly. When I do `sudo -u www-data bash`, I can read and write there just fine, but when the OpenResty worker process does that, it gets "permission denied" nonetheless.

The `client_body` directory was even auto-created by OpenResty and looks like this:

```
drwx------ 2 www-data root     4096 Dec  4 18:49 client_body
```

My first thought was that `ProtectHome` could be an issue, but I would have expected that to interfere also with the master process and not just the workers, plus I did set that to `false` already.

I added an `access_by_lua_block` in which I run `id` and log its output, and I get, as expected, this:

```
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

Interestingly though, if I use `/usr/local/openresty/nginx` as prefix path, everything works. (But I would prefer to have the Git repo in `/home/ubuntu/app/my-project`...) Also, if I configure OpenResty to run as user `ubuntu` and not `www-data`, it works too.

I am at the end of my knowledge here. What else could be wrong?

For the record, this is my `openresty.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=The OpenResty Application Platform
After=syslog.target network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/app/my-project
Type=forking
PIDFile=/home/ubuntu/app/my-project/logs/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -p /home/ubuntu/app/my-project
ExecStart=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -p /home/ubuntu/app/my-project
ExecReload=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload -p /home/ubuntu/app/my-project
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /home/ubuntu/app/my-project/logs/nginx.pid
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed
ProtectHome=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note: The answers to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/678139/nginx-doesnt-start-using-systemctl) suggested it could be an SELinux issue, however `sudo sestatus` outputs `SELinux status: disabled` for me (and trying to run `sudo semanage permissive -a httpd_t` anyway results in an error that the policy isn't managed, as expected).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The issue was that even though `/`, `/home`, `/home/ubuntu/app` and `/home/ubuntu/app/my-project` were accessible to `www-data`, `/home/ubuntu` was not (it was `750` with `ubuntu:ubuntu`).

I now decided to move the whole project directory to `/var/www/my-project`, adding `ubuntu` to the `www-data` group and keeping `/home/ubuntu/app/my-project` as symlink to `/var/www/my-project` while changing all the paths in the service unit file to `/var/www/my-project` as well. This solved the issue.

---

Now the part that threw me off and prevented me from realizing this sooner was this: It did work before when I tried `sudo -u www-data bash` and then used `ls /home/ubuntu/app/my-project/html` or `echo hello >  /home/ubuntu/app/my-project/temp/client_body/test`. However, after playing with this more, I realized that it *only* worked **when I had `/home/ubuntu/app/my-project` already as working directory beforehand**!

```
ubuntu@my-server:~/app/my-project$ sudo -u www-data bash
www-data@my-server:/home/ubuntu/app/my-project$ echo hello > /home/ubuntu/app/my-project/temp/client_body/test
www-data@my-server:/home/ubuntu/app/my-project$ cat /home/ubuntu/app/my-project/temp/client_body/test
hello
```

```
ubuntu@my-server:/var/www$ sudo -u www-data bash
www-data@my-server:/var/www$ echo hello > /home/ubuntu/app/my-project/temp/client_body/test
bash: /home/ubuntu/app/my-project/temp/client_body/test: Permission denied
```

This is doubly weird because in my service unit file the `WorkingDirectory` *was* defined to be that exact directory, but maybe OpenResty changed it before forking.

Anyway, if somebody has an explanation for this, please let me know in the comments!